# Take medicine, commerce (opt for/choose)

Tags: word-usage, american-english

We use "take" with individual subjects, to mean that the person "takes classes in that particular subject ". But in College,  can it be used to describe the "major" chosen, like "medicine" or "commerce"?

Like:

> I took Commerce in College.
>
> I took Medicine in College.

Does it mean "I studied Medicine in College " or "I chose Medicine in College"? Is the use of "take" common this way in AmE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using **to take** is not a natural way of expressing one's college major in AmE.  Note also that "college" is not capitalized unless it's part of the formal name of an institution (e.g., "Dartmouth College").

**I took physics in college.** This means that I enrolled in one or more physics classes, but leaves my major unspecified.

**I majored in physics in college.** This explicitly identifies what my major was.

**I studied physics in college.** This is ambiguous and could mean either it was my major or it was just a class I took.  The difference would have to be made in the surrounding context.

In short, **take** is used for individual courses or classes, not for entire courses of study, where you use the verb **to major [in]**.  For example:

> Q: Did you **take** physics in college?
>
> A: I didn't just **take** physics, I **majored in** it!

Comment: So might be used with "medicine"?

Comment: "I took medicine in college," does **not** mean that you took all the classes that are need for medicine - it just means that you took at least one class in "medicine".  This would be unusual to say since there's not a single discipline called "medicine", but it would be entirely normal to say, "I took **internal medicine** in college," because that is a single discipline.

Comment: What you would say with "medicine" is "I **majored** in medicine in college."  You can use "major" as a verb.

Comment: Is there a specific word for "choosing it or opting for it"?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The specific word is **majoring**. Why do you need a substitute for **major** when it's already a verb?  **Take** is used for individual subjects or classes, not entire courses of study.

Comment: So can "take" be used just for "choosing it" or will the word be "choose/opt for "?

Comment: I repeat - **take** is used for individual subjects or classes, not courses of study. It's fine to use "take" to mean "choose" if you're talking about choosing an individual class.  If you're talking about choosing a major, then you'd say, "I chose to major in medicine."

Comment: And can it simply be : "I chose medicine".

Comment: "I chose medicine" leaves it unclear whether you're talking about a single course or a course of study.  The surrounding context could make that more clear.

Comment: As "medicine" is relatively uncommonly discussed as a university course name, "I took medicine in college", without context, sounds like something you did because you caught a cold.

Comment: I would hesitate to say "I took medicine in college" in case people thought I was sick and required doses of cough syrup. Edit: simultaneous with @scatter.

Comment: To echo what was said in the second comment, we don't usually use "medicine" or "commerce" in the same way we use "physics" or "chemistry". A doctor might say, "I **studied** medicine," but wouldn't say, "I took medicine." Also, I've never heard anyone say, "I majored in commerce," but "I majored in business" is very [common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=majored+in+business%2Cmajored+in+commerce&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3).

Comment: And @J.R. can "major in" be used for a "field" as well rather than an individual subject? Like : "Medicine", "Engineering", "Commerce" or "Law" etc. Will only "study" be used with these? (Someone told me this...) Like : "I majored in physics." but it should be "I studied medicine".

Comment: "Major" is only used for undergraduate studies.  You seldom hear people say "I majored in medicine" because "medicine" is not typically an undergraduate degree, it's a professional degree that you study in medical school, not in college.